# HTML5: location of local DB

Tags: macos, html, localdb

I am a new bid in HTML5 please help me with this

I am creating a local DB via HTML% apis on client machine like this

```
function initDB(){
var shortName = 'stuffDB';
var version = '1.0';
var displayName = 'MyStuffDB';
var maxSize = 65536; // in bytes
localDB = window.openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
}
```

Is it possible to get the location of the DB created like
alert ("path of db is " + dbPath);

Thanks in advance
Ankit

Answer (score 0):

That information isn't available to the end user at all.  Although most, if not all, localDB engines use the same back end, the spec allows for the possibility that data may be kept somewhere else -- including the Windows registry -- so long as the localDB[1] engine acts the proper way.

[1] Not a realistic possibility, but not outside of the specs.